# Excel date functions

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get the current year/month/day military time in a cell. This is exactly what I need in the cell #Date:2017/AUG/14 14:55:08 I know this is super easy to do but I'm just not getting the result that I want.  This is what I tried.

```
="#Date"=date(yyyy,MMM,D, hh:mm)
```

Comment: Are you asking for VBA to write the date to a call in that format? Or for a formula to do it?

Comment: Your formula is wrong, it should be `="#Date"&date(yyyy,MMM,D, hh:mm)` (note the use of & to joing 2 strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're after VBA:

```
="#Date:" & Format(now(),"yyyy/MMM/D hh:mm:ss")
```

If you're after a cell formula:

```
="#Date:" & TEXT(NOW(),"yyyy/MMM/D hh:mm:ss")
```

Note: Consider `DD` instead of `D` if you want day 1 to read `01` instead of `1`

Answer (score 1):

Just enter:

```
=NOW()
```

in a cell and custom format as "#Date:"yyyy/mmm/dd hh:mm

Comment: You didn't add the `"#Date:"`.  For OP:  You can still reference the date as a real date with this method.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Thanks - I've added that in.